# how to use 'includes' correctly in vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to show an error message if object in an array has the string `FAILED`. My array looks like this:

[image]

And my code to check if one object has `state: "FAILED"` looks like this:

```
hasFailedTask() {
  console.log(this.model.status.tasks);
  return this.model.status.tasks.state.includes('FAILED');
},
```

but then I always get the following error message in my console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:587 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"
```

Does anyone know the problem and could support me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `tasks` is an array, and it contains objects `some` of which have a `.state` property with the value `'FAILED'`. There is no `tasks.state` property.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, how would it look in my code?

Comment: Just like @ASDFgerte just commented

Comment: Sorry, i removed my comment for various reasons. For completion's sake, it was `!arr.some(obj => obj.prop === 'FAILED')`, but i did not name the property as would be required, or the depth of the property in the related object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `find` method since  `this.model.status.tasks` is an array :

```
hasFailedTask() {
 
  return  this.model.status.tasks.find(task=>task.state.includes('FAILED'));
},
```

Answer (score 1):

your function should look like this:

```
hasFailedTask() {
  //console.log(this.model.status.tasks);
  return this.model.status.tasks.some(({state}) => state === "FAILED")
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flatMap to allow an includes check:

```js
hasFailedTask() {
    return this.model.status.tasks.flatMap(t => t.state).includes('FAILED');
}
```